# The SSL connection could not be established on Windows Runner for Github

Tags: github-actions, windows-server-2019, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have a Windows Server 2019 Data Center on which I am setting up github action runner.
Windows Version - 1809

While executing the command -

> ./config.cmd --url https://github.com/org/repo --token myPAT

I am getting the error -
**The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.**

I am seeing the same error while executing workflow which runs on runner which was already hosted on that machine. It was working but suddenly started getting this error.

full logs --

```
[2024-03-14 18:07:53Z ERR  ConfigurationManager] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'IllegalParameter'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at GitHub.Runner.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetTenantCredential(String githubUrl, String githubToken, String runnerEvent)
[2024-03-14 18:07:53Z ERR  ConfigurationManager] #####################################################
```

Comment: Any 1809 bits are end of life now, Windows 10 or Windows Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/windows-10-1809-end-of-servicing. Please use a supported version and try again.

Comment: But this was working from 2 months.. out of sudden it stopped

Comment: Not a surprise. Your luck just ran out. Unless you can reproduce the issue on a fully supported Windows release, there is nothing to discuss much.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling tls1.3 worked for me.